# Column of an existing data frame as a new data frame in R, but result is NULL

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` (name: sample) in R which I imported from an csv file containing 15 fields and 100516 columns. I want to create a new data frame "sample2" with 3rd column of "sample".

```
sample2 = sample[,3]
```

When I checked the `nrow(sample2)` the result is `NULL`.

But when I used `head(sample2)` I can see the content.

Comment: Because `sample2` is a `vector`, not a `data.frame`.

Comment: Is there any way to create it as dataframe , not as a vector.

Comment: @user3928988.  You could also use `subset(sample, select=3)`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are using `nrow` on a `vector`.

If you want to keep the `data.frame` structure when selecting a single column in this way, you need to add `drop = FALSE` when subsetting.

Consider the following example:

```
## Sample data
mydf <- data.frame(v1 = 1:2, v2 = 3:4)
nrow(mydf)
# [1] 2

## What you did
mydf[, 1]
# [1] 1 2
nrow(.Last.value)
# NULL

## What you wanted to do
mydf[, 1, drop = FALSE]
#   v1
# 1  1
# 2  2
nrow(.Last.value)
# [1] 2
```